# Избежать большого количество подзапросов SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

В WinForms приложении существует `dataGridView`, который заполняется около 1000 строк и 107 столбцов при входе в приложение из БД `MS SQL`.
Хранимая процедура, большинство данных возвращает через подзапросы следующего вида:

```
ISNULL(
    (SELECT top 1 departedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 1),
    (SELECT top 1 arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 1)
    ) as t2
```

Количество выше приведенных под запросов около 50 шт. Отличаются они фильтром `sort = N`. Прошу, подскажите способ утилизации такого количества подзапросов, цель - увеличить скорость ответа. Если бы задачу решал в Report Builder при создании отчета, фильтровал бы данные в столбцах инструментами Report Builder без использования подзапросов. На данный момент при количестве строк 986 столбцов 107, время выполнения около минуты. Все поля попадающие под фильтр индексированы.
Запрос из процедуры за исключением нескольких полей :

```
select distinct 
    dataRegistr.id,
    ISNULL(tripStatus.id,0) as id_Status,
    dataRegistr.shiftCode as shiftCode2,
    dataRegistr.dateDocument,
    0 as tripList,
    ISNULL(dataRegistr.transportKg, 0.00) as transportKg,
    ISNULL(dataRegistr.transportPal,0) as transportPal,
    ISNULL(dataRegistr.ref,0) as ref,
    ISNULL(dataRegistr.addPoint,0) as addPoint,
    ISNULL(dataRegistr.tarifPerHour, 0.00) as tarifPerHour,
    ISNULL(dataRegistr.tarifPerKm, 0.00) as tarifPerKm,
    ISNULL(dataRegistr.hourToPay, 0.00) as hourToPay,
    ISNULL(dataRegistr.kmToPer, 0.00) as kmToPer,
    ISNULL(dataRegistr.allSum, 0.00) as allSum,
    ISNULL(newRegistr.addressName,0) as p1,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 ISNULL(CASE WHEN addressCode IN (select region.regionCode from region) THEN addressName ELSE addressCode end,0) from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 1),0) as p2,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 ISNULL(CASE WHEN addressCode IN (select region.regionCode from region) THEN addressName ELSE addressCode end,0) from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 2),0) as p3,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 ISNULL(CASE WHEN addressCode IN (select region.regionCode from region) THEN addressName ELSE addressCode end,0) from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 3),0) as p4,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 ISNULL(CASE WHEN addressCode IN (select region.regionCode from region) THEN addressName ELSE addressCode end,0) from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 4),0) as p5,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 ISNULL(CASE WHEN addressCode IN (select region.regionCode from region) THEN addressName ELSE addressCode end,0) from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 5),0) as p6,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 ISNULL(CASE WHEN addressCode IN (select region.regionCode from region) THEN addressName ELSE addressCode end,0) from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 6),0) as p7,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 ISNULL(CASE WHEN addressCode IN (select region.regionCode from region) THEN addressName ELSE addressCode end,0) from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 7),0)as p8,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 ISNULL(CASE WHEN addressCode IN (select region.regionCode from region) THEN addressName ELSE addressCode end,0) from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 8),0) as p9,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 ISNULL(CASE WHEN addressCode IN (select region.regionCode from region) THEN addressName ELSE addressCode end,0) from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 9),0) as p10,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 ISNULL(CASE WHEN addressCode IN (select region.regionCode from region) THEN addressName ELSE addressCode end,0) from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 10),0) as p11,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 ISNULL(CASE WHEN addressCode IN (select region.regionCode from region) THEN addressName ELSE addressCode end,0) from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 11),0) as p12,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 ISNULL(CASE WHEN addressCode IN (select region.regionCode from region) THEN addressName ELSE addressCode end,0) from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 12),0) as p13,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 ISNULL(CASE WHEN addressCode IN (select region.regionCode from region) THEN addressName ELSE addressCode end,0) from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 13),0) as p14,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 ISNULL(CASE WHEN addressCode IN (select region.regionCode from region) THEN addressName ELSE addressCode end,0) from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 14),0) as p15,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 ISNULL(CASE WHEN addressCode IN (select region.regionCode from region) THEN addressName ELSE addressCode end,0) from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 15),0) as p16,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 ISNULL(CASE WHEN addressCode IN (select region.regionCode from region) THEN addressName ELSE addressCode end,0) from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 16),0) as p17,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 ISNULL(CASE WHEN addressCode IN (select region.regionCode from region) THEN addressName ELSE addressCode end,0) from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 17),0) as p18,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 ISNULL(CASE WHEN addressCode IN (select region.regionCode from region) THEN addressName ELSE addressCode end,0) from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 18),0) as p19,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 CASE WHEN addressCode IN (select region.regionCode from region) THEN addressName ELSE addressCode end from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 19),0) as p20,
    ISNULL(newRegistr.departedTime, newRegistr.arrivedTime) as t1,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 departedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 1),(SELECT top 1 arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 1)) as t2,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 departedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 2),(SELECT top 1 arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 2)) as t3,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 departedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 3),(SELECT top 1 arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 3)) as t4,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 departedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 4),(SELECT top 1 arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 4)) as t5,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 departedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 5),(SELECT top 1 arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 5)) as t6,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 departedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 6),(SELECT top 1 arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 6)) as t7,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 departedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 7),(SELECT top 1 arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 7)) as t8,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 departedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 8),(SELECT top 1 arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 8)) as t9,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 departedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 9),(SELECT top 1 arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 9)) as t10,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 departedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 10),(SELECT top 1 arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 10)) as t11,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 departedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 11),(SELECT top 1 arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 11)) as t12,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 departedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 12),(SELECT top 1 arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 12)) as t13,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 departedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 13),(SELECT top 1 arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 13)) as t14,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 departedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 14),(SELECT top 1 arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 14)) as t15,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 departedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 15),(SELECT top 1 arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 15)) as t16,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 departedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 16),(SELECT top 1 arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 16)) as t17,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 departedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 17),(SELECT top 1 arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 17)) as t18,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 departedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 18),(SELECT top 1 arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 18)) as t19,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 departedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 19),(SELECT top 1 arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 19)) as t20,
    ISNULL(newRegistr.arrivedTime, newRegistr.departedTime) as tv1,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1  arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 1),(SELECT top 1 departedTime  from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 1)) as tv2,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1  arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 2),(SELECT top 1 departedTime  from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 2)) as tv3,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1  arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 3),(SELECT top 1 departedTime  from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 3)) as tv4,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1  arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 4),(SELECT top 1 departedTime  from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 4)) as tv5,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1  arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 5),(SELECT top 1 departedTime  from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 5)) as tv6,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1  arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 6),(SELECT top 1 departedTime  from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 6)) as tv7,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1  arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 7),(SELECT top 1 departedTime  from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 7)) as tv8,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1  arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 8),(SELECT top 1 departedTime  from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 8)) as tv9,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1  arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 9),(SELECT top 1 departedTime  from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 9)) as tv10,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1  arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 10),(SELECT top 1 departedTime  from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 10)) as tv11,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1  arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 11),(SELECT top 1 departedTime  from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 11)) as tv12,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1  arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 12),(SELECT top 1 departedTime  from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 12)) as tv13,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1  arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 13),(SELECT top 1 departedTime  from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 13)) as tv14,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1  arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 14),(SELECT top 1 departedTime  from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 14)) as tv15,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1  arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 15),(SELECT top 1 departedTime  from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 15)) as tv16,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1  arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 16),(SELECT top 1 departedTime  from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 16)) as tv17,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1  arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 17),(SELECT top 1 departedTime  from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 17)) as tv18,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1  arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 18),(SELECT top 1 departedTime  from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 18)) as tv19,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1  arrivedTime from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 19),(SELECT top 1 departedTime  from newRegistr WHERE shiftCode = dataRegistr.shiftCode and sort = 19)) as tv20,
    dataRegistr.tripNumber,
    dataRegistr.region,
    dataRegistr.allDistance,
    dataRegistr.allHour,
    dataRegistr.allDistanceWithOrders,
    dataRegistr.successTKm,
    dataRegistr.managerName,
    dataRegistr.dateInsert,
    dataRegistr.registrName,
    dataRegistr.idTariffType,
    dataRegistr.isReturns
from dataRegistr
JOIN newRegistr ON dataRegistr.shiftCode = newRegistr.shiftCode and newRegistr.sort = 0
LEFT JOIN tripStatus ON dataRegistr.isTax = tripStatus.id
WHERE  CAST(dateInsert as date) = '2017-11-13' 
ORDER by dateInsert DESC
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68793/discussion-on-question-by-winteriscoming----).

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего тормоза из-за этого

WHERE CAST(dateInsert as date) = '2017-11-13'

Замените на

WHERE dateInsert >= '2017-11-13' AND dateInsert  < '2017-11-14'

и почитайте

http://www.interface.ru/home.asp?artId=10279

Comment: После того как переписал все подзапросы на PIVOT месяц формируется до 10 сек, до этого день около минуты. Но я воспользуюсь и вашим советом! Спасибо.